# NSArray safeguards

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

If there is a chance that an NSArray is empty, is it better to check it and set equal to nil if it's empty when it is assigned or to rather do the check when it is used?

e.g.

```
NSArray *myArray;

if ([anotherArray count] > 0)     <-- Check when assigned
  myArray = [anotherArray copy];
else
  myArray = nil;

something = [myArray objectAtIndex:x];
```

or

```
NSArray *myArray;

myArray = [anotherArray copy];

if ([myArray count] > 0)          <-- Check when used
  something = [myArray objectAtIndex:x];
```

Which is better?

Comment: Also for any other variable, NSArray was just the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Why are you setting it to nil if it's empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just check to see if the array is empty when necessary.

Don't set it to `nil`, this can cause other problems. For example, if you try to add the `nil` array to an `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` or other collection class, the runtime will throw an exception.

Comment: I thought setting to nil was the safe thing to do?!? I'll remember what you've said, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a question of programming style more than anything.

I'm guessing you're worried about allocating memory unnecessarily should a passed in array is empty

Comment: Exactly, besides not wanting to accidentally access an empty array I also don't want a useless variable taking up space.